# It seems to me that there are two candidate functions for the call g(parm, 1) in the example in [basic.lookup.argdep]/3

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup, unqualified-name

Example in [[basic.lookup.argdep]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#3):

```
namespace NS {
    class T { };
    void f(T);
    void g(T, int);
}
NS::T parm;
void g(NS::T, float);
int main() {
    f(parm); // OK: calls NS::f
    extern void g(NS::T, float);
    g(parm, 1); // OK: calls g(NS::T, float)
}
```

For the call `g(parm, 1)` we have in the set *X* the declaration `void g(NS::T, float);` in global scope. AFAICT, we also have in set *Y* the declaration `void g(T, int);` in namespace `NS`, an associate namespace of the argument `parm` of type `NS::T`. Thus, if I'm not wrong, the two declarations are candidates for overload resolution. Then, is it the case that the declaration in global scope is preferred in relation to the one in namespace `NS`? Why? I would very much appreciate a quote from the Standard as an answer.

Comment: Unqualified name lookup finds a viable candidate, and so lookup stopped.

Comment: @PasserBy Well [basic.lookup.argdep]/3 says explicitly `The set of declarations found by the lookup of the name is the union of X and Y.`

Comment: *"the lookup"* refers to ADL.

Comment: @PasserBy And that's exactly what I'm talking about. See this in [\[basic.lookup.unqual\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#unqual-3): `The lookup for an unqualified name used as the postfix-expression of a function call is described in [basic.lookup.argdep]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that section, we have:

> Let `X` be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup and let `Y` be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If `X` contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - **a block-scope function declaration that is not a *using-declaration*, or**
> - a declaration that is neither a function nor a function template
>
> then `Y` is empty.

Unqualified lookup finds the block scope function declaration - `extern void g(NS::T, float)`. Not the declaration at global scope `::g`.

Hence, `Y` is empty, which makes the union of `X` and `Y` trivially just `X`, which just contains that one declaration, which is a viable candidate.

If that declaration were not there, then unqualified lookup would find `void g(NS::T, float)` and we'd go on to perform ADL, which would find `N::g(T, int)`, which is a better match.

Comment: `void g(NS::T, float);` in global scope is **not** a block scope function declaration.

Comment: @WaldB That's true. But it doesn't contradict anything I said.

Comment: Oh, you have edited the answer. Great answer by the way. Thanks.

Comment: When I comment out the declaration `extern void g(NS::T, float);` the compiler still uses the function in global scope. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @WaldB You sure? If yes, that's a compiler bug.

Comment: Why do you think so? Both clang and g++ show the same result.

Comment: @WaldB Link demonstrating that?

Comment: Sorry for this. I was in hurry and said something that didn't correspond to reality. When I comment out the `extern` declaration both compilers use the function `g ` in namespace `NS`. Thanks again.